# Wortstellung in »Zeigen möchten wir nun, dass [...]«

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, writing

Ich spreche Deutsch als Muttersprache, hatte jedoch heute eine kleine Diskussion, die mich sehr verunsichert hat. In einer wissenschaftlichen (mathematischen) Arbeit habe ich geschrieben:

> Zeigen möchten wir nun, dass [...] gilt.

Daraufhin meinte ein Korrektor, dass dieser Satz doch niemals korrektes Deutsch sein könne – das sei eher »Meister-Yoda-Stil«.

Ich verstehe vollkommen, dass das keine Alltagssprache ist, war/bin mir aber sehr sicher, dass ich hier im Recht bin. Meinem Sprachempfinden nach ist das sogar eine etwas gehobenere Möglichkeit, »Wir möchten nun zeigen, dass [...]« auszudrücken (die Betonung wird ganz sanft auf *Zeigen* verschoben) und damit eigentlich nicht unpassend für eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit. Eine kurze Internetrecherche wiederum bestärkte eher die Zweifel – dort wird immer empfohlen, das finite Verb an die zweite Position im Satzbau zu positionieren (oder in Ausnahmefällen an eine andere Position, jedenfalls nie die erste).

Trügt mich mein Sprachgefühl? Hat jemand begründete Meinungen oder eine Quelle, die hier Klarheit schafft? Ich habe zwar nicht vor, das dem Korrektor vor die Nase zu halten, aber ich würde es gerne für mich selbst wissen.

Comment: "Meister-Yoda-Stil" wäre eher "Nun zeigen wir möchten, dass ... gilt". (Wenn ich http://www.jedipedia.de/wiki/Basic richtig interpretiere.)

Comment: 1. Der Satz ist korrektes Deutsch. 2. Der Satz klingt wegen der Inversion schräg und hölzern. 3. Er ist trotzdem richtig. 4. Das ist wenn, dann schlechter Stil - nicht schlechte Grammatik. https://wortwuchs.net/stilmittel/inversion/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Aussagesatz (Hauptsatz mit Nebensatz als Objekt)
- Personalform des finiten Modalverbs befindet sich an zweiter Stelle (es heißt ja `Ich möchte zeigen` und nicht `Ich zeige möchten`)
- Infinitiv kann im Vorfeld stehen

Also handelt es sich hier um korrektes Deutsch. Das einzige, was diese Konstruktion zu jener beginnend mit *wir* unterscheidet, ist - wie du richtig erkannt hast - die Betonung.

Comment: Es dürfte bei dieser Formulierung wohl auch darum gehen das Personalpronomen zu "verstecken" welche bei wissenschaftlichen Texten gerne vermieden werden um objektiver zu klingen.